# Apple Music detect is member

Tags: objective-c, ios9.3, apple-music

In iOS 9.3 Apple release new APIs. Now developers can see if a user is currently a member of Apple Music. I'm trying to understand how it works.
My code -only first time- asks the user whether to access the music library but I don't understand how to determine in what ways you can detect if user is a member and open Apple Music to join it. These actions in Shazam works really great. How can I do something like that?
Thanks in advance!

```
[SKCloudServiceController requestAuthorization:^(SKCloudServiceAuthorizationStatus status) {

    NSLog(@"status is %ld", (long)status);

    SKCloudServiceController *cloudServiceController = [[SKCloudServiceController alloc] init];

    [cloudServiceController requestCapabilitiesWithCompletionHandler:^(SKCloudServiceCapability capabilities, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSLog(@"%lu %@", (unsigned long)capabilities, error);

        if (capabilities >= SKCloudServiceCapabilityAddToCloudMusicLibrary || capabilities==SKCloudServiceCapabilityMusicCatalogPlayback) {

            NSLog(@"You CAN add to iCloud!");


        } else {

            NSLog(@"The ability to add Apple Music track is not there. sigh.");
        }

    }];

}];
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check for the `SKCloudServiceCapabilityMusicCatalogPlayback` flag in capabilities. The code in your question checks whether the capabilities variable equals that flag, but you need to use bitwise operators. Here is how you'll do that.

```
SKCloudServiceController *controller = [SKCloudServiceController new];
[controller requestCapabilitiesWithCompletionHandler:^(SKCloudServiceCapability capabilities, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error getting SKCloudServiceController capabilities: %@", error);

    } else if (capabilities & SKCloudServiceCapabilityMusicCatalogPlayback) {
        // The user has an active subscription

    } else {
        // The user does *not* have an active subscription
    }
}];
```

You can tell that `SKCloudServiceCapabilityMusicCatalogPlayback` is a flag and not just a regular constant value because the value uses bitwise operators (the "<<" shown in Apple's documentation).

```
SKCloudServiceCapabilityMusicCatalogPlayback = 1 << 0
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/storekit/skcloudservicecapability/skcloudservicecapabilitymusiccatalogplayback?language=objc